# How to perform calculation on kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to perform calculation on edit event for example Quantity * Rate = Amount.

This calculation want to do in kendo grid. Dojo Link attached. Please help anyone to achieve this. http://dojo.telerik.com/AtebI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there will be more possible solution, one from them can be something like this [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/AtebI/6). In this example I have used custom template for edit mode and calculation is done in js. You will need do just css modification etc. Hope, it helps to you.

Comment: Thanks.. But my requirement is in dynamic. I don't know how field will come for calculation. I have to generate dynamic function for that. is it possible to achieve. please help me.

Comment: Aha. If I understand correctly now, you need [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) event which run immediately after grid is rendered. [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/AtebI/12) here. Is that what do you need?

Comment: @Japi..I need the function like. Please see the example http://dojo.telerik.com/uPIVe. Here the calculate value is updating back to grid. please help me. Thanks in advance